# How can I manage reactjs component files in Rails, since the app now has so many reactjs components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem to work with Reactjs in my Rails application. Everything works well until the frontend becomes to have so many components which were defined in the separated file.

The problem is every time the application was loaded, all of those files were downloaded to the browser. I know it is obvious, but kind of inefficient, because only a few react component will be used in a session.

Here is my current workspace:

```
--assets
----javascripts
------components
--------component_1.js.coffee
--------....
--------component_n.js.coffee
```

I just wonder is there any working solution to optimize this?

Comment: Instead of throwing everything into `application.js` you could probably separate it into multiple files (one for each layout or major part of the app)

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I got your great idea, it is still complex because if we have more and more components, we will separate it again, Any conventional for this: eg for `/home` we only need `component_1`, and `component_2`?

Comment: I just started working with React myself not so long ago so I don't have enough experience to be honest. Some kind of dynamic loading of components would make sense but I'm not sure if anything like that exists in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactjs does not support this, but there are other libraries you can use (requirejs for example).

A very good open source solution is [LABjs](http://labjs.com/).

Another one is https://webpack.github.io/.

There are others. See [this discussion](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/dynamically-loading-react-components-from-server/1757) on reactjs site.